# is there a way to cast to a type by using a string

Tags: java, casting

I have a string that tells me what I want to cast my object to, Is there a way to cast to that object?

Here is some pseudo code that defines what I would like to do

```java
public TypeToCastTo Cast(T object, String TypeToCastTo) {
  switch (TypeToCastTo) {
   case "foo":
     return (foo)T;
   case "otherType":
     return (otherType)T;
   ...
  }
}
```

edit
I wanted to create a game where I can click on a button to purchase something e.g. sword or armour which inherits from worldObject. I figure since I might be returning a weapon or armour class (which both inherit from worldObject) that it would make sense to return a worldObject and then downcast to the correct class (Based off it's name (String)).

edit 2:
As mentioned in the comments this is an XY problem. I was originally trying to make a function that would return the downcast type but in reality that doesn't make sense, since in the case it is used somewhere else, i will need a switch statement to determine what to do with the object anyway (at this point i can cast) so rather than having

```
public TypeToCastTo Cast(T object, String TypeToCastTo) {
  switch (TypeToCastTo) {
   case "foo":
     return (foo)T;
   ...
  }
}
```

And using my function to cast the WorldObject, I can have

```
Method DoingSomethingWithWorldObject(WorldObject T) {
 switch(T.typeToCastTo) {
  case "foo":
    foo temp = (foo)T;
    // code using temp
  case "other":
    other temp = (other)T;
    // code using temp
  ...
 }
}
```

although several people mentioned it was probably wrong the way i was thinking of doing it, Including the answer i have marked correct (Which answered my question even though i was asking the wrong question), The reason i actually understood this was because of a response that was deleted.

Comment: Yes, with reflection, but not returned from a constructor though.

Comment: The method signature cannot be the name of the variable you're passing to the method.

Comment: You can use Reflection... but what is the use case here?

Comment: @mario_sunny,I return a parent class which has a GetName() method that returns the name of the type of the child that it should be cast to, I wasn't sure what else i could return

Comment: @AlfredoAwesomeMonazite No I mean, why would you not know the type of an object? I can understand there are a few scenarios where this may occur (ex. an object being returned from a third-party API), but those are few and far between. Just want to make sure you are not overengineering something. The type system is there for a reason. Refection should not be used unless necessary.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Use [edit] option and show what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @AlfredoAwesomeMonazite Could you post the bit of code where you purchase your items? that would help clarify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this by using reflection with the `Class.cast` method:

```java
public Object cast(Object object, String typeToCastTo) {
  switch (typeToCastTo) {
   case "foo":
     return Foo.class.cast(object);
   case "otherType":
     return OtherType.class.cast(object);
  }
}
```

However the return type of the method needs to be `Object` as you don't know the actual return type that is encoded in the `typeToCastTo` parameter.

That is it only makes at least some sense, if you have an instance of Class at hand:

```java
Class<Foo> fooClass = (Class<Foo>) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("my.foo.Foo");
Foo fooObject = foo.cast(object);
```

But all of this seems rather pointless...

Based on the comments. To invoke a parent class' private method, you don't need to cast:

```
Object object = new SubFoo();
Method privateFooMethod = Arrays.asList(ParentFoo.class.getDeclaredMethods())
    .stream().filter(m -> m.getName().equals("privateFooMethod")).findAny()
    .get();
privateFooMethod.setAccessible(true);
privateFooMethod.invoke(object);
```

But you should really think twice before using reflection to achieve something like this. This very much looks like a bad class/interface design resulting in weird solutions for rather basic needs.

Comment: What's the point of this? After the method, you still just have an Object? Also it seems to avoid  the question by using the concrete names.

Comment: I was hoping that i could use this method to determine what child class i should cast to to access their functions (that i won't have access to in the parent class)

Comment: @AlfredoAwesomeMonazite you don't need to cast an instance of a class to get access to it's methods. By using reflection and `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` you can get a class' methods and invoke on the uncast instance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach (though I don't know if it's considered bad practice):

```
public TypeToCastTo Cast(T object, String TypeToCastTo) {
  switch (TypeToCastTo) {
   case "foo":
     return new Foo(object);
   case "otherType":
     return new OtherType(object);
   ...
  }
}
```

You'll need specific constructors with corresponding parameters (overloaded) for the different types you'd like to address though. Within those constructors you can control the exact "translations" from one type to another.